# How to set a default entity relation in a property?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, default, entity-relationship

I have 2 entities, Contact and ContactType.
The owner entity is Contact, with a property $type :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Evo\BackendBundle\Entity\ContactType")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
protected $type = null;
```

I now have to set this relation to be mandatory. I tried the following :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Evo\BackendBundle\Entity\ContactType")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
protected $type = 2;
```

But I get an error, which is pretty logic. I should set an entity (with id 2) as default, not a integer. But I have no idea how to do this. I previously read I shouldn't do any query to DB or any use of EntityManager inside an entity. So how can I set a default ContactType ?

Comment: Try withRegistering an `Event Listeners` and on the creation of your entity find and attach the correct default ContractType to your entity. Hope this help

Comment: But i'll have to manually trigger the event everywhere I create a new Contact ? So there is pretty much no difference to set it manually directly in the controller with `$contact->setContactType($em->getRepository('ContactType')->find(2));` Or can I trigger this event automatically somehow in the Contact Entity so I have only one place to make script update ?

Comment: Sorry, i talk about [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) that are managed with the doctrine object lifecycle. Yes, you can do the job in the controller also, is only a method to separate the logic. In detail you can register a specific service on the `prePersist ` [doctrine2 lifecycle](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) and on your object add the specific relation to the contracttype.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution probably would be to put this logic in some kind of "manager" service, for example a ContactManager.

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class ContactManager
{
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function createContact(ContactType $type = null)
    {
       if (!$type instanceof ContactType) {
           $type = $this->manager->getReference('ContactType', 2);
       }

       return new Contact($type);
    }
}
```

Then define your service (for example in services.yml):

```
contact_manager:
    class: ContactManager
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

Comment: I tried the event listener solution given above, and it works pretty well. Why would a manager service would be a better solution ? Symfony docs seems to push the event listeners, I never read anything about manager services.